# Difficulty getting custom Google font working for Plotly Dash app

Tags: python, css, plotly-dash, google-font-api

I have a dash app and would like to utilize a custom google font. I'm having trouble getting it working. As per the google instructions I added the following to my CSS sheet in my assets folder.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Gruppo&display=swap');
body{
   font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive
}
```

This changes the font but to a generic dash cursive font and not the desired one.
I've tried setting the external stylesheets to the font URL to no avail. Any other tips?

```
FA = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poiret+One&display=swap"
external_stylesheets = [FA, dbc.themes.SLATE]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding `app.css.config.serve_locally = True`, this should ensure that the CSS stylesheet is loaded in the browser.

**app.py**

```py
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

external_stylesheets = [
    'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poiret+One&display=swap',
     dbc.themes.SLATE
]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.css.config.serve_locally = True

app.layout = html.Div([

    html.Div(
        children='Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.',
        style={
            'font-size': '200%',
            'margin': '2vw 0vw 0vw 2vw',
        }
    ),

])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='127.0.0.1', debug=True)
```

**styles.css**

```css
body{
    font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
}
```